# Submit form to servlet using JQuery Ajax

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, servlets

How can we submit Form to servlet when we click on span tag using Jquery Ajax, and get output from servlet?
Below is calculator example code.
If instead of span if i use input type="submit" i get the right result in index.html, but if i use span instead of input type for submit, i am directed to servlet page.

**index.html**

```
<form name="form1" method="POST" action="Ajaxexample" id="form1">
  <table>
   <tr>
     <td>Number 1</td><td><input type="text" name="n1"/></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td>Number 2</td><td><input type="text" name="n2"/></td>
   </tr>
    <tr>
     <td></td><td><span onclick="form1.submit()">Calculate</span></td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
       <td>Result</td><td><input type="text" value="" id="result"/></td>
     </tr>
    </table>
 </form>
    <script src="script/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    var form = $('#form1');
    form.submit(function () {

     $.ajax({
     type: form.attr('method'),
     url: form.attr('action'),
     data: value,
     success: function (data) {
     var result=data;
     $('#result').attr("value",result);
     }
     });
     return false;
     });
     </script>
```

**Ajaxexample.java**

```
     protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)throws 
     ServletException, IOException {
         response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
         PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

         int n1 = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("n1"));
         int n2 = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("n2"));

        out.println(n1 + n2 + "");

       }
       }
```

**web.xml**

```
      <display-name>Ajax</display-name>
     <welcome-file-list>
      <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
       <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
       <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
      <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
     <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
      <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
     <servlet>
         <servlet-name>Ajaxexample</servlet-name>
         <servlet-class>Ajaxexample</servlet-class>
         </servlet>
         <servlet-mapping>
         <servlet-name>Ajaxexample</servlet-name>
         <url-pattern>/Ajaxexample</url-pattern>
         </servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: What is "value" and how do you wire up the span.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have clearly written " onclick="form1.submit()">"  that's why form is submitting....

Remove onClick() method from submit &

```
     <span id="calc">Calculate</span
```

& replace

```
    form.submit(function () {
```

line by

```
      $( "#calc" ).click(function(){
```

Comment: Thanks for help, i did as suggested and i have changed POST to GET and also changed data:value to data:form.serializable inside ajax, i am still getting error as GET localhost:8080/Ajax/Ajaxexample [HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error 19ms]

Answer (score 6):

```
<span onclick="formSubmit();">Calculate</span>

function formSubmit(){

 $.ajax({
     url:'localhost:8080/Ajax/Ajaxexample',
     data: $("#form1").serialize(),
     success: function (data) {
            $('#result').html(data);
    }
});
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you form method is post `<form name="form1" method="POST" action="Ajaxexample" id="form1">` but you are writing codes in servlet `doGet()` so you may not proper results.Remeber that if the form method is `get` then in the servlet `doGet()` will be called and if the form method is `post` then in servlet `doPost()` will be called

Comment: Thanks, i have changed POST to GET but still not working and also changed data:value to data:form.serializable inside ajax, i am getting error  as  GET http://localhost:8080/Ajax/Ajaxexample [HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error 19ms]

Comment: @CY5 The syntax is `data:{parametername:parametervalue}`